# Getting the return value in "sh -e"

Tags: shell, sh

I'm writing a shell script with `#!/bin/sh` as the first line so that the script exits on the first error. There are a few lines in the file that are in the form of `command || true` so that the script doesn't exit right there if the command fails. However, I still want to know know the exit code of the command. How would I get the exit code without having to use `set +e` to temporarily disable that behavior?

Comment: Bash != `sh`, yet your question is tagged [tag:bash]. Please see [BashFAQ/105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) for reasons not to use `-e`.

Comment: The script is just a series of commands, and two of them give screwy exit codes, so I don't want to have to add error handling after every command just to accommodate for those two commands.

And I'm pretty sure bash is the same as sh in this respect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question appears to imply `set -e`.

Assuming `set -e`:

Instead of `command || true` you can use `command || exitCode=$?`. The script will continue and the exit status of `command` is captured in `exitCode`.

`$?` is an internal variable that keeps the exit code of the last command.

Since `||` short-circuits if `command` succeeds, set `exitCode=0` between tests or instead use: `command && exitCode=0 || exitCode=$?`.

But prefer to avoid `set -e` style scripting altogether, and instead add explicit error handling to each command in your script.

Comment: +1, but it's probably better to write `command && exitCode=0 || exitCode=$?` so that the exit-status is captured in `exitCode` even if the command succeeds.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Because if `command` returns a non-zero exit-code, then that will abort. There are few specific cases where `set -e` ignores a command's exit-code, and none of them applies to `command ; exitCode=$?`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know the status of the command, then presumably you take different actions depending on its value.  In which case your code should look something like:

```
if command; then
    # do something when command succeeds
else
    # do something when command fails
fi
```

In that case you don't need to do anything special, since the shell will not abort when command fails.
The only reasons `set -e` would give you any problems is if you write your code as:

```
command
if test $? = 1; ...
```

So don't do that.